# Trying to read first line of file using fgets

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that will read the first line of a txt file and output it. I can't get the fgets to display in my fprintf statement when running the program.

```
#include "example.h"

// function: main

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {

  //declare filepointer
  FILE *fp;

  //declare variables
  char c[10];
  long size;

  //open file
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  //first output read dimension of vector
  fgets (c, 10, fp);
  fprintf(stdout, "the dimension of the vector is %s\n", c);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

The text file has the following contents:

```
4
45.0
62.0
55.6
8.2
```

But my output is just reading as:
the dimension of the vector is

Comment: Do basic error checking - essential both to make code robust and to aid in debugging. In particular, check the result of `fopen` and `fgets`. Also check `argc` before accessing `argv`.

Comment: It's more conventional to use `printf(…)` than `fprintf(stdout, …)`.

Comment: what is the contents of the 'home grown' header file: `example.h`

Answer (score 2):

You always need to be careful of what the user is going to enter as input in the program. To do this, as mentioned in the comment, we should always check if the `fopen()`, `fgets()`, and the arguments are correctly passed before taking them into use.

---

Let's try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define EXIT_FAILURE 1
#define MAX_LEN      16

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char c[MAX_LEN];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror(argv[1]);

        fclose(fp); // Cleanup
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (fgets(c, sizeof(c), fp) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File read error.\n");
        fclose(fp); // Cleanup
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fprintf(stdout, "The dimension of the vector is %s\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, I've got those same values as yours in the `data.txt` file.

The program outputs:

```
rohanbari@genesis:~/stack$ ./a.out data.txt
The dimension of the vector is 4
```

Comment: `File not found.` is not a useful error message if there is a permission error. `if( fp == NULL ){ perror(argv[1]); ...`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I didn't know about that before. Thanks for that enhancement :)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Hmm... `sizeof c` seems great because it'll find the size. We can use `MAX_LEN` macro as well in this scope. Though, I've added it.

Comment: regarding: ` if (fgets(c, sizeof(c), fp) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File read error.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;`  This sequence will cause the program to exit with the input file still open.  As a general good practice should insert `fclose( fp );` before the `return` statement.
    }

Comment: @user3629249 *will cause the program to exit with the input file still open* – does this affect anything or anywhere...? From my perspective, in larger programs, it'll look like spam of `fclose`s in those places where `EXIT_FAILURE` is returned.

Comment: @RohanBari, you should always 'cleanup' before exiting.  It doesn't make much difference if running an OS, but it does make a big difference on real  time programs and when the program is running on 'bare metal'

Comment: @user3629249 Okay, I've followed the cleanup advice. That makes sense.